# How to count points in percentage that are within an extension defined by two pairs of coordinates

Tags: qgis, labeling, select-by-location, qgis-expression

Starting from a points geometry layer, my goal is to count points in percentage that are within an extension defined by two pairs of coordinates corresponding to the corners:

The initial situation is as shown in the following screen shot:

[image]

The goal would be to get to labeling the percentage of points that are within the extension and the percentage of points that are outside the extent. The idea behind this issue need is to use a labeling expression that avoids using a physical layer of polygons. I add a recreation of what I am looking for:

[image]

**Solution implementation**:

I have tried the [eurojam](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/87346/eurojam) user solution and the correction from [Xeppit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/151085/xeppit) user.

As you can see I have a layer of 10 points. 5 points are within the rectangle extension and 5 points are outside rectangle. Therefore the result should be 50%.

The rectangle has the following coordinates:

'lowerleft': '-0.00,-4.49'

'upperright': '5.40,4.45'

And the expression I use is:

```
round(with_variable(
'lowerleft',
'-0.00,-4.49',
with_variable(
'upperright',
'5.40,4.45',
with_variable('rect',
      make_rectangle_3points( 
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,',')[0]),to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,',')[1])),
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,',')[0]),to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,',')[1])),
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,',')[1]),to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,',')[1]))),
      aggregate(layer:='points',
         aggregate:='count',
         expression:=$id,
         filter:=intersects($geometry, @rect)))))
    / count($id) * 100,2) || ' %'
```

[image]

Comment: and where are the 2 pairs of coordinates come from? is it a layer, annotation, a user variable?

Comment: They are a user variable. The coordinates, in this case, define a rectangle. They are as follows:
Lower left side: _133.423,2.8251_ - _146.688,2.8251_
Upper left side: _133.423,21.2611_ - _146.688,26.2611_

Comment: I replaced '-' as delimiter with ',' in the make_point expression. because your lowerleft is '133.423,2.8251' instead of '133.423 - 2.8251' like in your first post...

Comment: Ok, now it is clear. However, although the expression now works, the result is not as expected. I add a screenshot. I would like if you could give me some hints as to where I am doing wrong

Comment: the next step is to override the position of the label: put it on the centroid of your rectangle. at the moment every point is labeled. you can use the definition of the rectangle which you use for the percent calaculation...

Comment: I have tried again with simpler data the expression implementation. Sorry, I am not able to find the reason why the result is not as expected. I explain the test I'm doing in the text question

Comment: It would probably be wise to edit your question down to focus on only the latest, simplified implementation. There is a lot of now-redundant material based on your previous attempts. Also, I see your project is in EPSG:3857, be aware that is a terrible coordinate system for conducting area or distance measurements. Try to use a local coordinate system if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can build an expression like the following one for a layer `points` and two user variables called `@lowerleft` and `@upperright`:

```
 with_variable('rect',
      make_rectangle_3points( 
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,'-')[0]),to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,'-')[1])),
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,'-')[0]),to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,'-')[1])),
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,'-')[0]),to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,'-')[1]))),
      aggregate(layer:='points',
         aggregate:='count',
         expression:=$id,
         filter:=intersects($geometry, @rect)))
    / count($id) * 100
```

According to user [Xeppit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/151085/xeppit) answer, a correction should be made so that the expression would look like this:

```
with_variable(
'lowerleft',
'-0.00,-4.49',
with_variable(
'upperright',
'5.40,4.45',
with_variable('rect',
      make_rectangle_3points( 
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,',')[0]),to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,',')[1])),
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,',')[0]),to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,',')[1])),
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,',')[1]),to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,',')[1]))),
      aggregate(layer:='points',
         aggregate:='count',
         expression:=$id,
         filter:=intersects($geometry, @rect))))
    / count($id) * 100) || ' %'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this proposed solution. I am trying to implement it but I think I have some syntax problem with the expression. I add more information to my question and ask for some more help to understand how I can make the expression work.

Answer (score 4):

There is a mistake in make_rectangle_3points geometry:

[image]

It should be

```
 make_rectangle_3points( 
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,',')[0]),to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,',')[1])),
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,',')[0]),to_real(string_to_array(@lowerleft,',')[1])),
         make_point(to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,',')[1]),to_real(string_to_array(@upperright,',')[1])
```

**--> Last line !**

[image]

Check your rect geometry with geometry generator in symbology of a seperate layer that you can see the selecting rectangle and adapt it to your needs.